# Can I delete this recursive link to my Home directory?

Tags: finder, symlink

My home directory has a symlink to my home directory. I'm not sure how it got there. Is it safe to delete?

```
~ steve$  ls -l steve
lrwxr-xr-x  1 steve  staff  12 Jun 21  2012 steve -> /Users/steve
```

[image: Home directory in Finder]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In command line you´ve more power with the following code line

```
cd ~ && unlink steve
```

so you´re shure that only the symlink will be deleted and not the complete home path :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply running `rm ~/steve` is safe:

1. specifying "~/steve"  (*not* "~/steve/", with a trailing slash) means `rm` will work directly on the link and not follow it, as it would if you enter "~/steve/".
2. even if you mistyped "~/steve/", deleting with `rm` will not delete a directory unless you give it a "-r" option.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** Providing you don't delete the contents of the symlink and just the symlink, you can delete the symlink fine. Just use ⌘⌫ on the symlink from Finder.